# Refactoring to Fetch API only once React.JS

Tags: reactjs

I am building a Project with the Pokemon API. Here it is how I am fetching the data:

pokeAPI.js

```
export const api = {

    getPokemonList: async ({ url }) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    resolve(data)
                })
        });
    },

    getPokemonInfo: async (url) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    resolve(data)
                })
        });
    }
};
```

App.js

```
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
  const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150';

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPokemonInfo = async () => {
      const json = await api.getPokemonInfo(URL);
      await loadPokemon(json.results);
    };
    getPokemonInfo();
  }, []);

  const loadPokemon = async (data) => {
    let pokemonData = await Promise.all(data.map(async pokemon => {
      let pokemonList = await api.getPokemonList(pokemon)
      return pokemonList
    }))
    setPokemon(pokemonData);
  };
```

Although this works, it's currently calling getPokemonList for every pokemon and the fact that there are multiple async / await is not helping with readiability. How could I refactor this logic:

```
  const loadPokemon = async (data) => {
    let pokemonData = await Promise.all(data.map(async pokemon => {
      let pokemonList = await api.getPokemonList(pokemon)
      return pokemonList
    }))
    setPokemon(pokemonData);
  };
```

to fetch only once, using a memoized value in a hook to prevent multiple re-renders?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

`there are several ways to do it, you can use redux like state managements or browsers local storage

```js
const App = () => {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let pokemons= localStorage.getItem("users");

    if (pokemons) {
      pokemons = JSON.parse(pokemons);
      setPokemons({ pokemons });
    } else {
      fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(pokemons => {
          setPokemons({ pokemons });
          localStorage.setItem("pokemons", JSON.stringify(pokemons));
        });
    }
  }, [])

}
```

Comment: Hi Ozan! The thing is, this first fetch, I'm able to get with only one fetch already. The problem is, after this 1st fetch, it returns me an array with the name and an url that is needed to get the information of each pokemon. So far, the only solution I got, was doing this function and storing the result in a variable pokemonData. But it runs once every pokemon fetched, 150, as is the case. I have a small project deployed at https://sortingdemo.braulioportela.com/, you can check out at the network tab how many times it's fetched after the 1st fetch, if you'd like to check. Thanks for helping.

Comment: oh but that's how pokemon api works. If you want specific information about pokemons you need to fetch each pokemon's characteristics. What you can do is store them somewhere so you don't fetch them again between refreshes and also you may want to use lazy load they also want you to store them locally as their api rule requests ``Locally cache resources whenever you request them.``

Comment: https://pokedex.stevenhansel.com/ check this awesome mans work, you may find similar ones when you google it